# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play­-services-­ads:18.3.0

Tags: android, gradle, ads

While syncing the project after added play-services-ads, I am always getting this error "failed to resolve play-services-ads".

**build.gradle at project level**

```
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**build.gradle at app level**

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.11.3'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play­services-­ads:18.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Your title has one spelling ('play-services-ads') and your gradle file has another ('play­services­ads').  Are you sure this file is causing that exact error?

Comment: thanx, i ve edited the question, yes its throwing error ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play­-services-­ads:18.3.0

Comment: Still doesn't match. Now one is `play­services-­ads` and the other is `play­-services-­ads`.

Comment: Edited both the places the play-services-ads

Comment: The title and build.gradle snippet still have a different spelling for play-services-ads

Answer (score 1):

Have you added apply plugin line in app level **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.11.3'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play­services-­ads:18.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' //add this
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Maven repos in allprojects.

Project build file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
```

Top level build file:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i have added the maven repo in allprojects but stil i am getting the same error